# How to change a point got based on a parent to another parent

Tags: wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml

How to change a point which is got based on Mainwindow to a panel which is a panel inside the MainWindow.

Say a mouse point got based on MainWindow and i need to know the same point based on another panel which is in the same window.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, MouseEventArgs allows you to specify relative to which element the mouse position should be calculated, by passing that element to [GetPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs.getposition.aspx)

```
var relativeElement = mainWindow;
var mousePosition = e.GetPosition(relativeElement);
```

Given such a point relative to one element, you could always use [TranslatePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.translatepoint.aspx) to translate it to coordinates that are relative to another element:

```
var panelPosition = mainWindow.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), panel);
```